# PrestaShop import items to show in iOS application

Tags: ios, prestashop

I have a new project in which I need to work on PrestaShop and create a universal mobile application. I am not getting anything anywhere about how you use it in an iOS application to get the items in different categories, Search API for items, etc.

Comment: Prestashop doesn't have an API. You only built for it. Otherwise choose Contus M Comm, We are readily built api for prestashop ios app solution. You can integrate your prestashop store into mobile app. It will sync automatically from your backend. This solution came up with latest features like deep linking, notifications, loyalty points, geo location etc.Just visit contus m comm

Answer (score 0):

PrestaShop implements a full-featured RESTful web service.

You need to enable the web service in Advanced Parameters > Web Service, then to use the guides and how-to located at http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Using+the+PrestaShop+Web+Service

You also have an example library on github: https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop-webservice-lib